# Best method for accessing an object in a flatbuffer builder before it is finished?

Tags: go, flatbuffers

I am building a node in flatbuffers that contain different object types and a signature of that object.

```
 ------------------
| Node             |
| object_sig       |
|  --------        |
| | Object |       |
|  --------        |
 ------------------
```

#### Pseudocode

The high level would look something like this.

```golang
builder := flatbuffers.NewBuilder(0)

bufs.ObjectStart(builder)
bufs.ObjectAddField(builder, field)
objectOff := bufs.ObjectEnd(builder)

obj := // TODO: get object

sig := ObjectSignFields(obj)

sigOff := builder.CreateByteVector(sig)

bufs.NodeStart(builder)
bufs.NodeAddSig(builder, sigOff)
bufs.NodeAddObject(builder, objectOff)
builder.Finish(bufs.NodeEnd(builder))

return builder.FinishedBytes()
```

#### Current Approach

I would like to access the object before the builder is finalized.

From reading the docs (and Go source), the method I have come up with is to clone the builder by copying its byte buffer to a new builder. There are a handful of non-public fields in the struct that do not get copied over but none of those are touched when calling `Finish()`.

```golang
shadow := flatbuffers.NewBuilder(0)
shadow.Bytes = make([]byte, len(builder.Bytes))
copy(shadow.Bytes, builder.Bytes)
shadow.Finish(objectOff)
obj := bufs.GetRootAsObject(shadow.FinishedBytes(), 0)
```

#### Questions

Is there a more official way to access an object before the builder is finalized?

Will the current approach be stable?